# A word/phrase/idiom for a person who is very valuable

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, idiomatic-language

I was writing a sentence when I got stuck. Which would be a perfect word or idiom for this sentence?

> *These days he is working on a computer generated music simulation project and **is already famous in the music industry and also every company wants to hire him**.*

The bold part is too lengthy and too wordy. I want to make it short and use a proper phrase or idiom at this place. I looked on the internet but found some incompetent idioms like : *buzz of the town*, *a valueable asset*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'These days he is working on a computer generated music simulation project and is already famous in the music industry and also every company wants to hire him.'

You may want to consider the following phrase

'a prominent and highly sought-after talent'

We need not repeat 'music industry'.